# Application of Cauchy's residue theorem

Tags: integration

I am trying to calculate this :

$I=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}}{a+ik} dk$

The pole is thus in $k=ia \;$ which is located in the upper plane (x>0).

$ I =  + 2\pi i \{\frac{e^{ikx}}{a+ik} \cdot (a+ik) \}|_{k=ia}$

$  I = 2 \pi i e^{-xa} H(x)$

where I add the heaviside function

**However** the answer in my book is precisely

$  I = 2 \pi e^{-xa} H(x)$

Without the imaginary number i

I don't understand why there is no longer i in this solution.

Comment: Since $k$ is the variable and $a$ the constant, you should have multiplied with $k - ia$ instead of $a+ik$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the residue by multiplying by $a+ik$ and evaluating at $k=ia$. You need to multiply by $k-ia$ and evaluate at $k=ia.$